# Including tom-select in typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, yarn-v2, tom-select

I'm trying to write a stimulus controller, so I create a file **blah.ts** with the only content:

```
import TomSelect from 'tom-select'
```

Running `yarn watch` results in:

```
ERROR in ./node_packages/bootstrap5/node_modules/@orchidjs/sifter/lib/sifter.ts:18:42
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@orchidjs/unicode-variants'. '/proj/symfony/node_packages/bootstrap5/node_modules/@orchidjs/unicode-variants/dist/umd/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/orchidjs__unicode-variants` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@orchidjs/unicode-variants';`
    16 |
    17 | import { scoreValue, getAttr, getAttrNesting, propToArray, iterate, cmp } from './utils';
  > 18 | import { getPattern, escape_regex } from '@orchidjs/unicode-variants';
       |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    19 | import * as T from './types';
    20 |
    21 | class Sifter{

ERROR in ./node_packages/bootstrap5/node_modules/@orchidjs/sifter/lib/utils.ts:2:27
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@orchidjs/unicode-variants'. '/proj/symfony/node_packages/bootstrap5/node_modules/@orchidjs/unicode-variants/dist/umd/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/orchidjs__unicode-variants` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@orchidjs/unicode-variants';`
    1 |
  > 2 | import { asciifold } from '@orchidjs/unicode-variants';
      |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    3 | import * as T from './types';
    4 |
    5 |

Found 2 errors in 178 ms.
```

We use yarn, so I tried `yarn add @types/orchidjs__unicode-variants --dev`, but this just gives:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types%2forchidjs__unicode-variants: Not found".
```

I don't know much about typescript, so I wonder could this be a bug in tom-select or perhaps something wrong with our webpack setup?
What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Enable `skipLibCheck` in your tsconfig.json

Comment: That one is already set to `true`